# Django: How to raise an exception when a user doesn't fill in a form at all?

Tags: python, django, forms

**How can I raise an exception when a user hits the "Submit" button on a registration form, without having filled in *any* of the fields on a form?**

---

In the event that this would happen, **I only want to display that single error** ("Please fill out the form before submitting."), without displaying the field errors that would typically be displayed if a user forgets to fill in a required field.

In other words, if a user hits the submit button without filling in a single field, I want it to display one error only: "Please fill out the field before submitting."

---

I figure there might be two ways to achieve this:

- Generate the error somewhere in the clean methods of the form; and have an if statement in the template that *disregards all other errors if this error is produced*.
- Generate the error *in the actual template*, as soon as the user hits the submit button (I'm not sure if this is even possible).

The problem with the first option is that I would need to use an if statement, like the one below. But I don't know how to single out that particular error.

```
{% if form.special_error %}
...display the special error
...disregard any other field or non_field errors
{% endif %}
```

I only know how to use `form.errors`, `form.non_field_errors`, and `form.<specific_field>` in if statements. None of these would specifically indicate that this special error occurred.

There has to be an easy way to do this!!!

Comment: why are you trying to do this at the template level, instead of the application server? Are you trying to do client-side checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the case you could just check on the server side if the form has changed instead of validating it. By doing this:

```
def submit_form(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
         form = Form(request.POST)
         if not form.has_changed():
             #Generate Error
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I've assigned the error to a variable called `fill_form_error`, passed the variable to the template using `context`, and used the if statement `{% if fill_form_error %}` ...display this error, ignore the rest... {% endif %}

Comment: Why not to add an error to existing form error handling system you say you're familiar with?

Comment: @KrzysiekSzularz It has to do with what I'm trying to do in the template. I have some sections in the html file that will only execute if certain errors are produced (such as `form.<specific_field>` errors). These sections will all be triggered if the user doesn't fill in the form (ie. "This field is required", "This field is required", etc.). The solution above allows me to use an if statement when the entire form has not changed, to not trigger the field-specific errors and associated sections of code (using `.hide()` in the if statement). Hope that's not too confusing!

Comment: Notice that as long as you don't call `is_valid` method field-specific errors are not going to be created at all. It was only a loose thought though. If it suits you – it's good solution after all.